# Why speed constant in uniform circular motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

In a uniform circular motion(earth orbiting the sun as an example), we say speed doesn't change.

If we take any moment, the force is perpendicular to the velocity direction.

[image]

The object was moving in y-direction with speed of 20m/s and perpendicular force to it was applied which caused $\vec v_1$ direction as shown. Since it was perpendicular, speed in $y$ direction didn't change, but its speed became non-zero in x-direction. so we got $v_{1magnitude} = \sqrt{v^2_{1y} + v^2_{1x}}$ which is in z direction.

Now, when it gets to the second point, perpendicular force was applied again and we got $\vec v_2$.  $\vec v_2 = \vec v_1 + \vec v_{perpendicular}$ so magnitude of $v_2$ changes

Could you explain how the speed doesn't change with my example ? ofc, force of perpendicular is constant, but it still changes magnitude. Why not ?

Comment: The magnitude of $v_1$ is most definitely not $v_{1x}+v_{1y}$, it is $\sqrt{v_{1x}^2+v_{1y}^2}$ why do you think it is the former?

Comment: sorry, made a mistake, but doesn't change anything in my question

Comment: Are you confusing _speed_, which does not change in uniform circular motion, with _velocity_, which does?

Comment: In fact, I'm ! but I have the same question how speed doesn't change because in order speed to not change, magnitude of velocity should be the same always. With my logic above, it's not

Comment: I updated to correct my mistake about magnitude

Comment: @noah i kind of followed it, but having hard time adjusting it to my logic. any chance, you could directly explain with my logic ?

Comment: I just came across the previous thread referenced above and found @Mark H's answer to be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec v_2 = \vec v_1 + \vec v_\perp \Rightarrow v_2=v_1\left( 1+\dfrac{v_\perp^2}{v_1^2}\right)^{1/2}\approx v_1\left( 1+\dfrac 12\dfrac{v_\perp^2}{v_1^2}+ . . . ..\right)$.

Note that the second term in the bracket is the square of the ratio of the change in speed to the original speed and thus, if $v_\perp\ll v_1$, ie the interval of time over which the velocity charges is very small, then $v_2=v_1$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a + sign in the square root and in the series expansion?

Comment: Why couldn't your argument be applied to any acceleration, even in one dimension where v1 = v0 +a$\Delta$t ? If the interval $\Delta$t is very small then v1 = v0 and nothing would ever accelerate.

Comment: Consider a ball thrown horizontally from a height at the earth's surface. Gravity is vertical so the horizontal speed doesn't change throughout the motion. But there is acceleration in the vertical direction, i.e. as in OP's question it is perpendicular to the initial velocity. Here, the vertical speed continually increases AS DOES THE OVERALL SPEED. How is this case different from that of an object in circular orbit?

Comment: @Not_Einstein For circular motion the direction of the change in velocity is always at right angles to the original velocity which is not true for projectile motion.

Comment: agreed, given the different motions, but here we're trying to explain why the motions are in fact different. I referenced above Mark H's answer in a previous thread which I found convincing.

Comment: @Farcher and we're back again to calculus. You mention " which the velocity charges is very small, then 2=1". note "very small" but not zero. so v2 is not equal to v1, but slightly bigger. like super small.